# How to resize image that captured from camera and display on imageview

Tags: java, android

now i develop an android app that need to upload image to my server. but when i try load image to imageview it just show blank. when i change the resolution from 1300 pixels to 300 pixels then the image can display at `ImageView`. my Code i like below. Please help

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
                    viewImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgInv);
                    int width = viewImage.getWidth();
                    int height = viewImage.getHeight();

                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                    bitmapOptions.inDither = true;
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),bitmapOptions);

                    viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path,String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    imgName = mName + "_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                    imgData = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
         }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting a valid `bitmap` ? could you just add logs and see the `bitmap.getHeight()` and `bitmap.getWidth()` ?

Comment: Why do you do this: bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

Comment: i follow the code that i found online.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not talking about your code but there is a library for what you want.
 You can use `Picasso` library that has complete features for working on images like as downloading, caching etc.
You can get it from [here](https://github.com/square/picasso) with an example.
Also there is a [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149) about it